# Intellij doesn't recognise courgette packages

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, courgette

I have installed the plugins, yet I can't get Intellij to correctly recognise my test environment. Not sure what I'm missing.

[image: test run]

[image: plugins]

pom

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
            <artifactId>system-rules</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
            <artifactId>fest-assert-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0M10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.monochromata.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>reporting-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.84</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.prashant-ramcharan</groupId>
            <artifactId>courgette-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
            <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mock-mvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-json</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-path</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>browserstack-local-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- apache POI dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>openxml4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion><
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
            <version>6.15.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>edge-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Edit with an error on Maven
[image: maven]

Comment: Looks like the plugin does not add any libraries to the compile class path.  I wouldn't expect it to either.   It just adds functionality to the IDE.   Add the appropriate jar file(s) to the project's dependencies.  If you're using Maven then add them to the project's POM for example.

Comment: @JJF edited with my pom

Comment: I dont know the package so I don't know what to tell you to put into the pom.  I do know sometimes I've seen IJ have trouble resolving new dependencies.   Have you tried manually "Reload All Maven Projects" to force it to re-read your POM?  The reload can be triggered by the little re-cycler icon below the word 'Maven' in the Mave tool Window.  Sometimes I even try File|Invalidate Caches...

Comment: it seems a maven error itself. I edited with an error in the Maven tool window

Comment: Did you put your code in `src/main` or `src/test`? Your courgette dependency is test scoped, so it should be the latter.

Comment: In regards to the Maven error: Assuming you have the repositories defined correctly, check those Artifacts' folders in your Maven Local for .lastUpdated files and remove them (or remove the entire folders).